# Driving simulation while on front jackstands

Tags: troubleshooting, drivetrain

I have a 2007 Tacoma, 4WD. I wanted to perform a driving simulation but with the truck being still in order to troubleshoot a rattling sound I can't reproduce when the engine is idling but the transmission is in neutral. It only happens when the truck is driven at times.

Is it safe to put the transmission in gear while the engine is on and the front of the truck is supported on adequately sized jackstands, while the rear wheels are down? Of course, not putting it in 4WD...

Comment: Is it the front wheels that are driven when in 2WD mode?

Comment: I'd advise you buy 2 more jack stands and lift the whole truck. The Tacoma has a 4x4 transfer case so in 2WD it's RWD.

Comment: That doesn't really sound right but I'll check

Comment: Now I would really like to see an example of a 4WD vehicle that does only drive the front wheels in 2WD mode.

Comment: Sounds pretty dangerous.  Can you put me on your life insurance policy?

Answer (score 5):

No. The rear wheels are ALWAYS driven in all Toyota Tacoma models. There is no mechanism to disconnect the rear wheels, while there is a transfer case to engage/disengage the front wheels. Most AWD cars that only drive the front wheels until more traction is needed use a transaxle. Toyota also does not sell a FWD only Tacoma, but they do sell RWD only versions.

Comment: So are you saying my truck is rear wheel drive when it's in 2WD ? That doesn't sound right

Comment: Yes, the truck is RWD when 4WD is not engaged. Another reason for this is to support the towing payload, if it were FWD, the payload would be reducing traction to the driven wheels. What makes you think it drives the front wheels?